# Why does ambiguity not raised for ArithmeticException parameter method

Tags: java, exception, arithmeticexception

Below code executed with out any compilation error of ambiguity, and output is **`ArithmeticException`**. Can you help me to know the reason?

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        testMetod(null);
    }

    // Overloaded method of parameter type Object
    private static void testMetod(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    // Overloaded method of parameter type Exception
    private static void testMetod(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }

    // Overloaded method of parameter type ArithmeticException
    private static void testMetod(ArithmeticException ae) {
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Question is why null is passed as `ArithmeticException` and no as `Object`or `Exception`.

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this the rule is to [match the most specific method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). Since `ArithmeticException extends Exception` and `ArithmeticException extends Object`, there is no ambiguity: `ArithmeticException` is more specific than any of the others.

If you add this though:

```
private static void testMetod(String string) {
    System.out.println("String");
}
```

You will get a compilation error because neither `ArithmeticException extends String` is true, nor the other way around: there is no single most specific parameter class.

*It's probably important to say at this point that all this is happening at compile time. Once the target method is resolved and the code is compiled, a call to an **overloaded** method is just like a call to any other method. This is in contrast with method **overriding**.*